# Groovy JSON slurper check child element failed

Tags: groovy, count, jsonslurper

I have this JSON input

```
{ "field": "AAA", "list": { "item": [ { "field01": "111", "field02": "222" }, { "field01": "333", "field02": "444" } ] }}
```

I need to do something on this json based on this condition: item count > 0.
I'm trying this code.

```
def myJson = '..' //above json; def jsonParser = new JsonSlurper(); def jsonObject=jsonParser.parseText(myJson); jsonObject.list.item.size()
```

But when item doesn't exist I get an exception. How can I get a value telling me item exists under list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use safe navigation operator `jsonObject.list.item?.size()` it will return `null` if `item` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

To check, if there is a item:

```
if (jsonObject.list.item)
{
  // do your things...
}
else
{
  // no item, so what?
}
```